# Is there a way to roll back all django app migrations?

Tags: django

I'm bootstrapping a new django project, and my team usually makes a 'setup/reset' script that rebuilds containers as well as drops(unless it doesnt exist yet) and rebuilds the database from scratch.

I found the `manage.py flush` command for dropping the data, but I also want to revert all migrations.  I could only find a command for rolling back the migrations of a single app at a time:

`manage.py migrate <app_name> zero`

Is there a way I can do that for *every* app, or would I have to list them out in the script?  We do have the `manage.py migrate` command that migrates everything, so I basically just want the opposite of that.

If it's not easily possible, I'll probably just make the db container drop  and rebuild the database

Thanks!

Comment: Rebuilding sounds good, unless there is any important data in it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have django-extensions, python manage.py reset_db sounds like what you're looking for.

Answer (score 15):

The good way is to use Django tools :

```
python manage.py migrate my_app zero
```

To reverse the migrations in the database [Reversing migrations : Django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/migrations/#reversing-migrations)

Then, manually delete the migrations you don't need in my_app/migrations

And finally, your are back to clean project :

```
python manage.py makemigrations my_app
python manage.py migrate my_app
```

Enjoy !!

Answer (score 3):

```sh
python manage.py showmigrations | grep -P "^[^ ]" | xargs -I {app} python manage.py migrate {app} zero
```

> If it's not easily possible, I'll probably just make the db container drop and rebuild the database

Honestly removing the db is way easier than letting Django unapply. I'm just adding this answer in case anyone wants a one-liner for other purposes.